# Open, Modify, SaveAs an Excel Workbook in the background (Winforms, C#)

Tags: c#, excel

in my app, I've saved a copy of a blank excel file form as a resources, I need to load this file, modify its both worksheets, save it in a new location with a new name.
user should not see that process.

I'm using C# 2010 with a SQL server, from which I'm gonna load my data and put it in the excel form.

Thank You For Your Time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Microsoft Interop Assemblies that can be found in .NET or COM (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel) 
Then load all the required cells into a `List` and modify the data.

Something like this (code below):

```
 string path = @"C:\temp\test.xls";
   ApplicationClass excelApllication = null;
   Workbook excelWorkBook = null;
   Worksheet excelWorkSheet = null;

   excelApllication = new ApplicationClass();
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
   excelWorkBook = excelApllication.Workbooks.Add();
   excelWorkSheet = (Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
   // Attention: 1 indexed cells, [Row, Col]
   excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Column A, Row 1";
   excelWorkSheet.Cells[2, 5] = "Column E, Row 2";
   excelWorkSheet.Cells[3, 3] = "Column C, Row 3";

   excelWorkBook.SaveAs(path, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);

   excelWorkBook.Close();
   excelApllication.Quit();

   Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorkSheet);
   Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorkBook);
   Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApllication);
   excelApllication = null;
   excelWorkSheet = null;
   //opens the created and saved Excel file
   Process.Start(path);
```

That should happen inside a Thread, because you don't want a user to notice that task.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
(Threading Tutorial)

Comment: First, thanks for your nice piece of code, but as i could get your code, you build a blank excel file, not using one that already exists, right? I need to use an excel file that already exists in my solution resources.

Comment: It wasn't wrong, i even rolled back and coped your old answer, cos i want to save it a new location, but how can i open it from my project's resources' path? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Add the file via Resources --> Add exisiting file.
Rename it to "excelfile" for example.
This is your code in my case:

 `string sPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(sPath, Properties.Resources.excelfile);`

Then use sPath in your project as the needed reference.

You're welcome.

Comment: Forgive me my ignorance, but what does `Process.Start(path);` is supposed to do?

Comment: It opens the Excel file in Excel. So you can directly view it. It's not essentially needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid automating Excel if at all possible and use the OpenXML SDK (or a library wrapping the OpenXML SDK) for this task.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830.aspx) is an article that could help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to do this... at least worked for me. :)

```
    private void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string newDirectoryPath = ValidateDirectory();
        string newFilePath = Path.Combine(newDirectoryPath, "new.xls");

        //brand new temporary file
        string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
        //to manage de temp file life
        FileInfo tempFile = new FileInfo(tempPath);
        //copy the structure and data of the template .xls
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath,Properties.Resources.SomeResource);

        Excel.Application xlApp;  
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(tempPath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        //WorkTheExcelFile();

        tempFile.Delete();

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(newFilePath);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);

        Process.Start(newFilePath + ".xlsx");
    }
```